# take from a string specific values

Tags: javascript

Hello I want to take fro a string i javascript specific values , the string has this format

```
[
    {
        "st_asgeojson": "{\"type\":\"MultiLineString\",\"coordinates\":[[[23.4582348,37.5062675],[23.4577141,37.5066109],[23.4572601,37.5070038],[23.4566746,37.507301],[23.455698,37.5076256],[23.4549737,37.5079214],[23.4545445,37.5080235],[23.4538579,37.5078873],[23.4325504,37.5231202],[23.4324646,37.5234265],[23.4324646,37.5236308],[23.4326363,37.5237669]]]}"
    },
    {
        "st_asgeojson": "{\"type\":\"MultiLineString\",\"coordinates\":[[[23.4568043,37.5042114],[23.4566078,37.5040436],[23.4567394,37.5038528],[23.4571075,37.5037422],[23.4575424,37.5035515],[23.4580841,37.5031548],[23.4589958,37.5027237]]]}"
    }
]
```

from this string i want to make an new 2d array , in this array i want to put only the coordinates.
for example i want to have in first row the first  `st_asgeojson` coordinates `[23.4582348,37.5062675],....,[23.4326363,37.5237669]` and the second row the other `st_asgeojson` coordinates `[23.4568043,37.5042114],[23.4566078,37.5040436],......,[23.4589958,37.5027237]`.

Is this posible to do it ?

i try to `str.split("[ ]")` but is show me the same as the string i have first.

Comment: This is JSON. You have to use a JSON parser (JavaScript has it built-in, it's `JSON.parse()`) for parsing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original string is JSON, so you first have to convert it to an array with `JSON.parse()`:

```
var arr = JSON.parse(str);
```

Then the value of the `st_asgeojson` property is another JSON-encoded object, so you'll have to parse that as well:

```
var first_coords = JSON.parse(arr[0].st_asgeojson).coordinates[0][0];
var second_coords = JSON.parse(arr[1].st_asgeojson).coordinates[0][0];
```

There's no `[ ]` anywhere in the string, so I'm not sure what you expected `str.split('[ ]')` to achieve. Did you mean to use a regexp, `str.split(/ /)` to split it on the spaces?

To get them all with a loop do:

```
var arrLeng = arr.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrLeng; i++) {
    var coordArray = JSON.parse(arr[i].st_asgeojson).coordinates;
    var coordArrLeng = coordArray.length;
    for (var j = 0; j < coordArrLeng; j++) {
        var coords = coordArray[0][0];
        var coordLeng = coords.length;
        for (var k = 0; k < coordLeng; k++) {
            alert(coords[k]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sory my explanesion is not good . I try to take the coordinates and show them alla the coordinates with a loop.

Comment: i try this but it is not work 
΄var arraLeng = arr.length;
var len=0;
while(arraLeng != len){
for (i=0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {
   for (j = 0; j < coordinates[i].length; j++) 
   { alert(JSON.parse(JSON.parse(arr[len].st_asgeojson).coordinates[i][j]); }
}
len++;
}΄

Comment: You need to parse the inner JSON before trying to access coordinates.length. Otherwise you get the length of the JSON string, not the array that it parses to. I've updated the answer.

Comment: i have a type of json array like  {"type":"MultiLineString","coordinates":[[[700041.580641594,4350337.62590304],[699997.9547992,4350258.09934122],[699963.62608879,4350169.87209629],[699956.583950972,4350110.57827156],[699856.434241901,4349955.60205613],[699851.705586662,4349903.89271632],[699870.84884414,4349828.45037377]]]},{.....}
I use the code you give me but is not work is say 
JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: My answer is for the array you posted in the question. That's not the same, the coordinates there in your comment aren't in a string so they don't need to be parsed.

Comment: How i take the coordinates ?

Comment: Just access them using normal Javascript array notation: `var.coordinates[i][0], var.coordinates[i][1]`